# Problem customizing a CSS stepper using Jquery or Vanilla Js

Tags: javascript, stepper

I am creating a Mullti-phase form using HTML and CSS which works fine. It has got a stepper at the top whereby I want to disable the 2nd and subsequent fields until a submit event is triggered on a button of the 1st phase. The code below controls the steppers. It has custom ids to control each stepper. When I add disabled property to the code the steppers dont move. How can I use vanilla Js or some jquery to make sure **only the 1st phase is shown while others are disabled when a user first visits and  form** and **subsequent phases only appear when an event is triggered in the previous phase** ?

~ Thanks

Js Fiddle link for CSS and HTML code

http://jsfiddle.net/8c4ktyq5/

**Raadio buttons that controls the steppers**

```
   <input checked='checked' id='step-1' name='step' type='radio'>
    <input id='step-2' name='step' type='radio'>
    <input id='step-3' name='step' type='radio'>
    <input id='step-4' name='step' type='radio'>
    <input id='step-5' name='step' type='radio'>
```

Comment: In your **JsFiddle** you cannot select/target anything other than the step/progress bar at the stop..

Comment: @NewToJS Sure,.. I have tried to simplify the huge code as seen in JsFiddle,,, Just wanted an idea of how to change the steppers after an event is trigggered on a phase of the form using JavaScript or Jquery,, am a bit new to Js